# C++ MFC, Custom Grid with CheckBox, RadioButton

Tags: c++, mfc, win32gui

I want to create Custom Grid which shall have inline edit feature, Checkbox, Radio button and Images.

I came across very good article << http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control;
Here DrawFrameControl is used to draw Check box and Radio Button

I have a requirement to customize the look and feel of check box.
Is it possible to customize DrawFrameControl's or is a good idea to create custom control (check box and radio button)?
Will there be any performance issue in case of custom controls?

Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: As a side note: MFC is one of those things Microsoft stopped doing more than minimal bug fixes on YEARS ago. It's really not a good choice for new projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't customize DrawFrameControl. It uses the system standard to draw the control.

If you need to customize it you have to draw the items by yourself. But using an image list it shoudn't be complicated to. Using CImageList is well documented everywhere ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; You mean, To have images like.. one for checked other for unchecked etc... and replace on user action?

Comment: Just intercept WM_LBUTTONDOWN... and WM_KEYDOWN